# Are there no consequences in Criston killing Joffrey during a royal wedding ceremony?

Tags: plot-explanation, house-of-the-dragon

In *House of the Dragon* Ep 5, ***We Light the Way***, Rhaenyra and Laenor are getting married. And both of them agree that their marriage is more of a political alliance.

Rhaenyra's personal guard and love interest, Criston beats Laenor's lover Joffrey to death in public.

But from there, there seems no any form of consequences in this crime.

- Criston murders a person in a royal wedding
- The victim is Laenor's lover

How is this logical? Criston simply switches to Queen Alicent side and becomes her personal guard. Is it implied he has been pardoned by Alicent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because he was upholding his vows as a member of the Kingsguard.
While we do not know what the exact wording of the vows to be we do know some specifics:

> [this elite group of knights sworn to father no children, hold no
> land, and protect the king and his family at all costs.](https://www.hbo.com/house-of-the-dragon/character-guide#criston-cole)

Being that Rhaenyra is the daughter of the King and heir, she also falls under this oath.

So When Joffrey says:

> “You don’t know me Ser Criston, but we are both deeply invested in
> this union.”
>
> Criston: “If you have something to say Ser Joffrey, speak it.”
>
> Joffrey: “Ser Laenor is quite dear to me. As I know the Princess is to
> you. We should swear to each other to guard them, and their secrets,
> because if those are kept safe, then so are we all.”

Christon knows what he is implying that the two of them are lovers, as it is truthful.

However the reason he got away with it is ***even the rumor*** of impropriety is seen as harmful to Rhaenyra but also the King.

In Season 1 Episode 4 of *House of the Dragon* Viserys fires Otto for the rumor, a mercy because as Rhaenyra says:

> “I am the princess. To question my virtue is an act of treason”

Comment: If I remember right, Joffrey was also carrying a knife in his hand when he died so Ser Criston can just lie and say he was trying to assassinate someone in the royal family. The scene kind of showed how chaotic the entire event was so there'd be no way to argue.

Comment: It can be that but Episode 5 is set up by Episode 4 which was built around starting the division of the Greens and the Blacks. By Otto questioning her virtue, and then being punished for it, lines were beginning to be drawn. Because of how quickly Alicent takes Criston under her wing, then his confession to her and their subsequent alliance. It makes more sense that he just said, "He was questioning her virtue," as it would play into Alicent and Criston's hand. Spreading of the rumor, but Criston gets out of trouble.